# 97 Mazda 323: Where is the IAT sensor?

Tags: mazda, sensor, lantis-323, iat

On my [97 Mazda 323 BA 1.8L BP-DOCH](http://en.mazda-club.eu/sub-model/mazda-323-familia-protege-iv-ba-bh-1) I can't seem to find the IAT sensor.  It has a [B6BF MAF](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=B6BF%20maf&biw=1680&bih=902&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=TWYSVbzdPIPzaq_9gOAI&ved=0CCMQsAQ) with a 5 pin connector, but I don't see anything else between the air filter and the throttle body.

On the similar 96 Protege 1.8L [the IAT is located in the air filter cover](http://www.autozone.com/repairguides/Mazda-323-MX-3-626-MX-6-Millenia-Prot%C3%A9g%C3%A9-1990-1998-and-Ford-Probe-1993-1997/ELECTRONIC-ENGINE-CONTROLS/Intake-Air-Temperature-IAT-Sensor/_/P-0996b43f80cb0ea3) next to the MAF.  It clearly has an IAT, since I see a reading for it when I hook up to the ECU, but I can figure out where it is.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so it seems like the IAT on this model is integrated with the MAF:

[image]

Comment: Way to follow-up with your question! I have often wondered why manufacturers don't put the IAT in with the MAF more often. It would make more sense (IMHO).

Comment: @Paulster2 Apparently Mazda has been doing this for a while - this particular MAF is still used in allot of their various models.